# Fix Application launcher from Java 1.6 Legacy to Oracle Java 7

Tags: terminal, applications, mojave, java

I'm using a Mac Pro 64bit Mojave.

Is it possible to create a `.command` or `.sh` or some other low-effort "launcher" for a Java program where all of the compiled code is in the "plugins" dir that does not open a terminal?

My situation is this: I'm tasked with making an old Java 1.6 project, once compiled, work under Java 7 on Mac Mojave.

Initially my issue was that the compiled launcher demanded Java 1.6 "legacy" be installed first where this is a contraint that no, we must not install other JREs before running the app.

But I figured ou that if I make a .sh file which runs the app by pointing the Java 7 binary and passing in the main plugin as an argument I can run the app successfully:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
\ -classpath /SOFT/corporateAppName/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0v2.jar
\ org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main
```

If I then change the `.sh` to `.command` I then have a runner from GUI, no need for terminal to start it.

This *could* be acceptable for the client *if* it didn't also open a terminal.

The reason I'm not instead trying to have my build generate a mac binary that does not fail with with legacy Java 1.6 needed is because I feel that that is not likely to be doable/ might require a year of work :

1. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7131356
2. https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/37
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507016/no-java-runtime-error-in-os-x-10-10-using-oracles-1-8-0-jvm
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009058/even-though-jre-8-is-installed-on-my-mac-no-java-runtime-present-requesting-t
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks

The common solution to this seems to be to give in and install the version of Java that macOS asks for and it will not really use it, only for init, or migrate to a version of Java in which the bug is not present (10+) neither of which are an option.

Unless there is actually a way I can change my jenkins-ant-cocoa build process in order for it to generate a launcher that would not present this bug, or also altering the binary launcher in a way that fixes this.

Comment: You could use Automator to make a script that runs a shell script

Comment: again, this would require the client install something extra.

Comment: Why not try bundling it into an app? Then you can just place the shell script in the MacOS folder of the app, and it'll work like a normal macOS app.

Comment: Yeah, you can run a shell script from inside an application without opening terminal

Comment: how do you do this?

Comment: This looks like an Eclipse RCP - you can put the path to the JRE in the xxx.ini file for the RCP, no need for any script.

Comment: interesting, although I suspect the syntax is different and spaces won't be authorised... I immagine `-classpath plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main` won't work because of the spaces and `-classpath=plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main` either because of the space. how would the syntax differ? would it have to be split into two variables?

Comment: @greg-449 also there's the problem that the launcher already calls java. but incorrectly so. and will lift the "need java 1.6" error message regardless of what I add to the .ini.

Comment: The RCP launcher executable uses the Java specified in the .ini file. The Java 1.6 required message is due to problems in the Info.plist - fixed in newer versions of Eclipse. Build the RCP using a current Eclipse (2019-03 for example) and there should not be any problem. I have several RCPs running on macOS without doing anything special.

Comment: the project isn't built with eclipse it's built with jenkins as I said. If I can know which compoenent to update in jenkins then I could apply the same fix you said. Jenkins is running ant + cocoa to build the app. it is as you said `Info.plist` is responsible for this message. I was able to create a launcher thanks to this solution : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps and copying back the other elements of my existing malfunctioning launcher one by one I worked out that it was `Info.plist` that was responsible. I would prefer jenkins spit out the correct launcher dirrectly.

Comment: here are the versions I uncovered in the Jenkins administrator configuration : `jdk1.7.0_75 apache-maven-3.2.3 apache-ant-1.9.6`